# Define the probability space, determine if it is uniform, describe the event above, and calculate its probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Question:

Suppose $5$ digits are chosen randomly. Find the probability that no digit exceeds $5$. For example: $01345,21003,32123,...$

Define the probability space, determine if it is uniform, describe the event above, and calculate its probability.

My attempt:

1. PROBABILITY SPACE:

Since we are selecting $5$ digits with repetition, the probability space is defined as follows

$ = \{00000, 00001, 00002, ........, 99997, 99998, 99999\}$

Hence, we can see that the sample space has whole numbers from $0$ to $99999$

Since each digit has $10$ ways to choose from

⇒Total number of outcomes = $10^5 = 100000$

2. DETERMINE IF IT IS UNIFORM:

In the above sample space, the probability of every outcome in  is the same. Hence the probability space  is said to be uniform.

3. DESCRIBE THE EVENT ABOVE:

The above event suggests that we need to choose each $5$ number from a set of $6$ numbers $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ to ensure a combination of number with its element is a digit less than or equal to $5$.

4. CALCULATE ITS PROBABILITY:

At each of the $5$ number slots, there are $6$ possible options.

⇒Total number of outcomes with no digit exceeds 5 is $6^5 = 7776$.

Dealing with uniform probability spaces is straightforward because the probability of any event  ⊆  is Pr[E] = |E| / ||

⇒ Pr[E] = |E| / || = $7776 / 100000 = 0.0778.$

Comment: Hello! Your working looks right. Please try to use mathjax for your questions in future: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry, you are saying that each string from $00000$ to $99999$ is equally likely to be hit?  How do you hit $99999$?

Comment: Seriously, though.  Learn how to format.  Writing $105$ to mean $10^5$  or $65$ to mean $6^5$ is silly.